# Calculate gesture distance in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the distance traveled during a Gesture. I can get the distance between two points using MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP or MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE. But that doesn't account for moving in say, a circle. It would calculate 0 because you moved all the way back around. I'm looking for total distance traveled, preferably in pixels so I can manipulate it further, if needed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the *historic* stuff of the MotionEvent. Based on the example of the API Doc you could do something like so (for simplicity my example doesn't deal with multi-touch):

On ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP do this, where `startX`, `startY` would be the last known coordinates, e.g. from last ACTION_DOWN event.

```
float getDistance(float startX, float startY, MotionEvent ev) {
    float distanceSum = 0;
    final int historySize = ev.getHistorySize();
    for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {
        // historical point
        float hx = ev.getHistoricalX(0, h);
        float hy = ev.getHistoricalY(0, h);
        // distance between startX,startY and historical point
        float dx = (hx - startX);
        float dy = (hy - startY);
        distanceSum += Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        // make historical point the start point for next loop iteration
        startX = hx;
        startY = hy;
    }
    // add distance from last historical point to event's point
    float dx = (ev.getX(0) - startX);
    float dy = (ev.getY(0) - startY);
    distanceSum += Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return distanceSum;
}
```

[image: example image]

Comment: This works really good. Although if you retrace the gesture back it will count down instead of up. I'm still pretty new to this, so it could just be my implementation. Thanks though.

Comment: Due to sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) the distance value should always increase. There will nevery be a negative value here.

Comment: It's the same format as the event-coordinates, so pixels basically, although due to diagonal lines there will be fractional values.

Answer (score 2):

A first order approximation would be to sum up the local length of every tiny piece of movement detected :

On `ACTION_DOWN`

```
total = 0;
xPrec = ev.getX();
yPrec = ev.getY();
```

On `ACTION_MOVE`

```
final float dx = ev.getX() - xPrec;
final float dy = ev.getY() - yPrec;
final float dl = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
total += dl;
xPrec = ev.getX();
yPrec = ev.getY();
```

On `ACTION_UP` you can do whatever you want with `total` which contains the total approximated length of your path.

If you read the official documentation about `MotionEvent` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html you will see a section entitled **Batching** which explains that one given motion event can batch together multiple movement samples. For the best first order approximation you need to consume all those samples using 
`getHistorySize`, `getHistoricalX`, `getHistoricalY`. Don't forget to process the most recent sample which stands in `getX` and `getY`.

If you need a better approximation I suggest you to read about the problem of curve fitting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting, but as the frequency of touch events is quite fast you may not need to do so and get satisfied with a first order approximation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the *best* way, but you could capture the data point each time MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE fires into an array and then calculate the cumulative distance from point to point to point ... to point upon completion of the gesture.